# I am writing a kafka consumer but I want to pause it and resume after particular timestamp

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

```
@StreamListener(value = DataFeedConstants.DATASTREAMINPUT)
 public void MethodName(@Payload(required = true) PojoClassName kafkaInputMsg,
                                    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String  key,
                                    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partitionId,
                                    @Header(KafkaHeaders.CONSUMER) Consumer<?,?> consumer,
                                    @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Long offset,
                                    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                                    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) Long recordTime) {
// business logic

if (offsetTracker.isOffsetExceeding(topicPartition, offset)) {
                Set<TopicPartition> pausedPartitions = consumer.paused();
                Set<TopicPartition> assignedPartitions = consumer.assignment();
                
                if(!pausedPartitions.contains(topicPartition)) {
                    //pause the consumer for the given partitions
                    consumer.pause(Arrays.asList(topicPartition));
                    //get the latest paused partitions
                    pausedPartitions = consumer.paused();
```

but now @StreamListener is deprecated. How to manage kafka consumer in functional approach. How to pause and resume it.

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Bean
java.util.function Consumer<Message<PojoClassName>> input() {
    return msg -> {
        msg.getHeaders().get(...., Consumer.class))...;
        ...
    };
}
```

However, you should NEVER pause the consumer this way because the listener container knows nothing about the pause and the partition will be resumed on a rebalance.

When the container is told to pause the partition, it will deal with rebalance and re-pause if that partition is re-assigned to this instance.

Comment: By doing as you suggested msg.getHeaders().get("kafka_consumer",Consumer.class) will return the consumer instance ? on that can I perform following things ?
   Set<TopicPartition> pausedPartitions = consumer.paused();
   Set<TopicPartition> assignedPartitions = consumer.assignment();

Comment: can you please elaborate on this. I couldn't get this one.
"listener container knows nothing about the pause and the partition will be resumed on a rebalance"

Comment: Yes, it's the equivalent of the `@Header` usage.  If a rebalance occurs, any partitions that are revoked and then re-assigned to the same instance will be resumed by the `KafkaConsumer`. If the listener container was used to pause the partition(s), it will re-pause them automatically after a rebalance.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, @Gary Russell. One more query related to rebalancing. It is the same behavior as earlier correct? As in at the time of ```StreamListener``` if I am using this ```Header ```and pausing the Consumer it is showing the same behavior like "it will re-pause them automatically after a rebalance."

Comment: Yes; the same applies to `@StreamListener` you should NOT pause the consumer in your code.

Comment: @Garry Russell thank you very much. So basically we have one requirement where consume all messages from start to offset at a particular time of the day once like a batch job. For this requirement, we are pausing and resuming consumer. Is there any alternate way for this ? Like if pausing is not recommended.

Comment: @Garry Russell I was able to get headers but I am not able to Pause the consumer. I am not able to pause it ```Consumer<?> consumer = headers.get("kafka_consumer", Consumer.class); ``` trying to get consumer like this but getting only accept method.

Comment: Looks like you have the wrong `Consumer<?>`, the kafka consumer has two wildcards `Consumer<?, ?>` but, once again, you should NEVER cause `pause()` on it. You need to pause the container instead.

Comment: @Garry Russell ```@Bean
Consumer<Message<PojoClassName>> input() {
    return msg -> {
        msg.getHeaders().get(...., Consumer.class))...;
        ...
    };
}``` for this type of bean it will import ```java.util.function.Consumer```   ```Consumer<?, ?>``` for this one  ```org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer``` is required right? So the bean you suggested and this one imports different Classes. Any reference can you provide where I can see imports and all

Comment: Don't put code in comments; edit the question instead. The fact that you are using `java.until.function.Consumer` elsewhere in the same class is irrelevant. It means you need to fully qualify one of them with the package name - `@Bean java.util.function.Consumer<....` or leave that as is and fully qualify the header value type.

Comment: @Garry Russel Thank you for the answer. It helped us. I just wanted to know if there is any other way to do this. Like creating a scheduler consumer but not with this pause as it is not recommended.